# return matches in a list with list of regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

I have a string if the alphabetical part of a word is more than 3 letters, I want to store that in a list. I need to store "hour" and "lalal" into a list.
I wrote a regex pattern for alpha-digit and digit alpha sequences like below.

```
regex = ["([a-zA-Z])-([0-9])*","([0-9])*-([a-zA-Z])"]
tring = 'f-16  is 1-hour, lalal-54'
for r in regex:
    m = re.search(r,tring)
    d.append((m.group(0))
print(d)
```

But this obviously gives me all the alphanumeric patterns which are being stored too. So, I thought I could extend this to count the letters in each pattern and store it differently too. Is that possible?

Edit: Another example would 
tring = I will be there in 1-hour
and the output for this should be ['hour']

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've tried so far and explain what doesn't work about it. Also, it helps if you provide an example of what you think the output should look like.

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: could you provide more examples that the solutions given do not capture

Comment: I edited to add another example which might make more sense. Does this help?

Comment: @Sue_ka: Thank you for adding more samples and clarifying your post. I've updated my answer which hopefully is what you were looking for. Let me know if you need anything else further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to only capture alphanumeric text if either it is preceded or followed by a number and a hyphen. You can use this regex which uses alternation for capturing both the cases,

```
([a-zA-Z]{4,})-\d+|\d+-([a-zA-Z]{4,})
```

**Explanation:**

- `([a-zA-Z]{4,})` - Captures the alphanumeric text of length four or more and stores in group1
- `-\d+` - Ensures it is followed by hyphen and one or more digit
- `|` - Alternation as there are two cases
- `\d+-` - Matches one or more digits and a hyphen
- `([a-zA-Z]{4,})` - Captures the alphanumeric text of length four or more and stores in group2

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OMh9bj/1)**

Check this python code,

```
import re

s = 'f-16  is 1-hour, lalal-54 I will be there in 1-hours'

d = []

for m in re.finditer(r'([a-zA-Z]{4,})-\d+|\d+-([a-zA-Z]{4,})',s):
 if (m.group(1)):
  d.append(m.group(1))
 elif (m.group(2)):
  d.append(m.group(2))

print(d)

s = 'f-16 is 1-hour, lalal-54'

arr = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]{4,}', s)
print(arr)
```

Prints,

```
['hour', 'lalal', 'hours']
```

Comment: But if there were longer words which aren't alphanumeric here, then this would give wrong results. I want to find the alphabetical part of each alphanumeric pattern.

Comment: Thanks Taurus for edit. I misread that the captured word should be three or more where as it is more than three.

Comment: @Sue_ka: Above solution will capture more then three alphanumeric part no matter how long or short the string is. Perhaps I am not getting what you are trying to point out. Can you please add some more samples in your post and expected captures? That will help validate what you are looking for.